# How can I create a custom THREE.MeshStandardMaterial?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking to create a material with three.js identical to MeshStandardMaterial.
I want to do this because I need all of its features except with small changes to the GLSL code.

I attempted to recreate MeshStandardMaterial using ShaderMaterial.

```
WAFFLE.StandardMaterial = function( parameters ) {

parameters.uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [
    THREE.UniformsLib.common,
    THREE.UniformsLib.aomap,
    THREE.UniformsLib.lightmap,
    THREE.UniformsLib.emissivemap,
    THREE.UniformsLib.bumpmap,
    THREE.UniformsLib.normalmap,
    THREE.UniformsLib.displacementmap,
    THREE.UniformsLib.roughnessmap,
    THREE.UniformsLib.metalnessmap,
    THREE.UniformsLib.fog,
    THREE.UniformsLib.lights,
    {
        emissive: { value: new THREE.Color( 0x000000 ) },
        roughness: { value: 0.5 },
        metalness: { value: 0 },
        envMapIntensity: { value: 1 } // temporary
    }
] );

parameters.vertexShader = THREE.ShaderChunk.meshphysical_vert;
parameters.fragmentShader = THREE.ShaderChunk.meshphysical_frag;

THREE.ShaderMaterial.call( this, parameters );

}

WAFFLE.StandardMaterial.prototype = Object.create( THREE.ShaderMaterial.prototype );
WAFFLE.StandardMaterial.prototype.constructor = WAFFLE.StandardMaterial;
```

I haven't been successful thus far.

How can I recreate MeshStandardMaterial?

Comment: You could do it as proposed by WestLangley [HERE](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10764) but I think it would change att instances of MeshStandardMaterial